# CPU usage overload with Ffmpeg in Video Upload Converter site

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overloading, cpu, converters

i am working on a video converter site in which you can upload a video an then convert it to the format you want.

Everything works great only problem is CPU usage overload of ffmpeg, when I upload 4 instance 4 HD videos CPU usage gets to 70-80%

To control this I would like to find a way to low cpu usage or priorizy it, I tried several tutorials like: http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/

but don't seem to control that, I tried this and then ffmpeg didn't work had to update it.

So once i control CPU usage I would also like to use a php queue system to control video conversion.

Could anyone give me any tips, orientation on how to get this working?

Thank you in advance

BTW My server is Centos Linux 6

Answer (score 1):

You could lower the
[number of threads](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html)
for FFmpeg

```
ffmpeg in.mp4 -threads 1 out.mp4
```

Comment: i was finally able to control priorities, now I'm trying to find some documentation in creating the queue system in php, I want to do something like this I found, http://pastebin.com/CNXp3yU1

Comment: But I don't know how to implement it